# How to use APIs hosted on local host in flutter mobile app: Spring Boot and Flutter

Tags: android, windows, flutter, spring-boot, localhost

I have created a **Spring Boot Web Application** and APIs to be used in a Flutter Mobile App. I am running my application on local host with url like-

> http://127.0.0.1:8086/assessmentportal/authenticate/verifyemail/reset-password-otp

I want to use the APIs in my flutter app (running on a physical device). I have read various answers and articles like https://medium.com/@podcoder/connecting-flutter-application-to-localhost-a1022df63130.
But this method is not working for me.
Code for API calls is-

```
class API {
  final sendEmailOTPUrl =
      "http://127.0.0.1:8086/assessmentportal/authenticate/verifyemail/sendotp";
  final verifyEmailOTPUrl =
      "http://127.0.0.1:8086/assessmentportal/authenticate/verifyemail/verify-otp";

  final Dio _dio = Dio();
  Future<Map<String, String>> sendEmailVerificationOTP(
      {required String? email}) async {
    Map<String, String> data = {"email": "$email"};
    Response response = await _dio.post(sendEmailOTPUrl, data: data);
    log("Response obtained: $response");
    Map<String, String> result = jsonDecode(response.data);
    return result;
  }

  Future<Map<String, String>> verifyEmailVerificationOTP(
      {required String? email, required String? otp}) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = {"email": email, "otp": int.parse(otp!)};
    Response response = await _dio.post(verifyEmailOTPUrl, data: data);
    Map<String, String> result = jsonDecode(response.data);
    return result;
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error in my flutter app-

```
E/flutter ( 3127): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.other]: SocketException: Connection refused (OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111), address = 127.0.0.1, port = 34222
E/flutter ( 3127): Source stack:
E/flutter ( 3127): #0      DioMixin.fetch (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:488:35)
E/flutter ( 3127): #1      DioMixin.request (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:483:12)
E/flutter ( 3127): #2      DioMixin.post (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:97:12)
E/flutter ( 3127): #3      API.sendEmailVerificationOTP (package:assessmentportal/NewtworkUtil/API.dart:16:36)
E/flutter ( 3127): #4      _RegisterScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:assessmentportal/Register%20and%20Login/RegisterScren.dart:80:45)
E/flutter ( 3127): #5      _InkResponseState.handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:1072:21)
E/flutter ( 3127): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:253:24)
E/flutter ( 3127): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:627:11)
E/flutter ( 3127): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:306:5)
E/flutter ( 3127): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:239:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:615:9)
E/flutter ( 3127): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
E/flutter ( 3127): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
E/flutter ( 3127): #13     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:617:13)
E/flutter ( 3127): #14     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
E/flutter ( 3127): #15     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:127:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #16     GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:460:19)
E/flutter ( 3127): #17     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:440:22)
E/flutter ( 3127): #18     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:337:11)
E/flutter ( 3127): #19     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:395:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #20     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:357:5)
E/flutter ( 3127): #21     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:314:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #22     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:295:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #23     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:167:13)
E/flutter ( 3127): #24     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:341:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #25     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:94:31)
E/flutter ( 3127): 
E/flutter ( 3127): #0      DioMixin.fetch.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio_mixin.dart:643:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #1      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658:54)
E/flutter ( 3127): #2      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 3127): #3      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
E/flutter ( 3127): #4      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
E/flutter ( 3127): #5      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
E/flutter ( 3127): #6      _SyncCompleter._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
E/flutter ( 3127): #7      _Completer.completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:23:5)
E/flutter ( 3127): #8      Future.any.onError (dart:async/future.dart:617:45)
E/flutter ( 3127): #9      _RootZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1658:54)
E/flutter ( 3127): #10     _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:162:22)
E/flutter ( 3127): #11     Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:778:47)
E/flutter ( 3127): #12     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:799:13)
E/flutter ( 3127): #13     Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:574:5)
E/flutter ( 3127): #14     Future._asyncCompleteError.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:665:7)
E/flutter ( 3127): #15     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
E/flutter ( 3127): #16     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
E/flutter ( 3127): 
I/ViewRootImpl@aa5f3e2[MainActivity]( 3127): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
```

From the error I can see that my phone is not actually using port 8086.
Also, I am using ethernet on my laptop and Wi-Fi (mobile hotspot created from my laptop), to ensure that both devices are on the same network.
Please help me to figure out what is going wrong and what should be done.